# What was the biggest punishment given by Canada against a U.S. spy?

Tags: united-states, canada, espionage

> OTTAWA—New figures show Canada has turfed out five spies in the past
> decade from a surprising source country — its best friend and ally,
> the United States.
>
> From 2004 to 2014 Ottawa sent back to the U.S. five of a total of 21
> of those barred from Canada “on security grounds for engaging in an
> act of espionage that is against Canada or that is contrary to
> Canada’s interests,” according to a document produced by Canada Border
> Services Agency.
>
> It’s not clear whether the espionage was by foreign government agents
> or whether it was industrial espionage — that is, spying to obtain
> state secrets or spying that targeted intellectual property or
> corporate secrets.

https://www.thestar.com/news/canada/canada-turfed-out-more-spies-to-the-u-s-than-elsewhere/article_47f12eac-6252-5f9e-a119-c358fa19ca4c.html

What was the biggest punishment given by Canada against a U.S. spy? The article doesn't mention what punishment was given, except the fact that spies are regularly being kicked out of the country and sent back, so the biggest punishment that is made known is expulsion, but I am wondering if any of them were charged and sentenced to serve a sentence or similar in Canada.

Comment: As per you other very similar Q here (about Europe), most of those Americans probably had diplomatic immunity/cover.

Comment: Also the piece you quote seems to use "spies" loosely in that quote. Elsewhere it says "suspected spies were permanent residents or foreign nationals deemed inadmissible on security grounds". So "suspected", not necessarily proven.

Comment: And as further explained there, if a foreigner doesn't contest the deportation order (or even if he does initially, but then withdraws the objection and leaves "voluntarily") he's not counted in those statistics. They illustrate it with a Russian guy example.